# Help with improper integral

Tags: integration, improper-integrals

$$
\int_0^\infty\frac{e^{-x}}{\sqrt{x}}dx=\int_0^1\frac{e^{-x}}{\sqrt{x}}dx+\int_1^\infty\frac{e^{-x}}{\sqrt{x}}dx
$$

I can't solve the integral so I try to use limit comparison. For the 1 to infinity integral I use
$$
e^{-x} > \frac{e^x}{\sqrt{x}}
$$
and I get that it's convergent.

But the left integral I go from $0$ to $1,$ I don't know how to solve. Since if $\sqrt{x}$ is under $1$ then it gets bigger.

Comment: $$I=\sqrt{\pi}$$

Answer (score 2):

For $0 <x<1$ we have $\frac 1  e \frac 1 {\sqrt x} <\frac {e^{-x}} {\sqrt x} <\frac 1 {\sqrt x}$ and $\int_0^{1} \frac 1 {\sqrt x}dx=2\sqrt x|_0^{1}=2$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\sqrt x = t \Rightarrow \frac{1}{\sqrt x}dx = 2dt$ and $x = t^2$

The integral becomes,
$$2\int_0^\infty e^{-t^2}dt = \sqrt\pi\int_0^\infty\frac{2e^{-t^2}}{\sqrt\pi}dt = \sqrt\pi \cdot\text{erf}(\infty) = \sqrt\pi$$